# Ubercart and Drupal 7 - hook_add_to_cart

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, ubercart, githooks

http://www.ubercart.org/docs/api/hook_add_to_cart

I am trying to hook into the add cart functionality of ubercart. I have created stock_control.module and stock_control.info files and enabled the module. In my .module file I have

The first is output but the 2nd is not.

```
<?php
   dsm('hello1');
     function stock_control_add_to_cart($nid, $qty, $data) {
    dsm('hello2');
     if ($qty > 1) {
    $result[] = array(
  '        success' => FALSE,
  'message' => t('Sorry, you can only add one of those at a time.'),
);
  }
  return $result;
 }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the hook in version 7 is [`hook_uc_add_to_cart`](http://api.ubercart.me/api/drupal/ubercart!uc_cart!uc_cart.api.php/function/hook_uc_add_to_cart/7).